# Air hockey multiplayer-how can I constantly move the pictureBox from input coming through a client application.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, network-programming

I'm trying to move the picture box on Host(a simple server) screen through data coming from client computer. It's a simple pong game which is multiplayer. Client sends data whenever the keys are pressed. It mainly sends the Y axis location of the pictureBox but I get error when I try to change the location of picture box. My client code which sends the Y axis location of the player1 pictureBox to server player..

```
private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        goup = true;


    String s = Convert.ToString(player.Location.Y);

    byte[] byteTime = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

    ns.Write(byteTime, 0, byteTime.Length);
}
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        godown = true;

    String s = Convert.ToString(player.Location.Y);

    byte[] byteTime = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

    ns.Write(byteTime, 0, byteTime.Length);
}
```

}

My server program which is receiving the data

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

TcpListener listener;

TcpClient client;

NetworkStream ns;

 Thread t = null;


public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();

listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4545);

listener.Start();

client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

ns = client.GetStream();

t = new Thread(DoWork);

t.Start();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String s = textBox2.Text;

byte[] byteTime = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

ns.Write(byteTime, 0, byteTime.Length);
}
public void DoWork()

{

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while (true)

{

    int bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    string data;
   this.SetText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead));

   // data = (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead));

   // int Y = Convert.ToInt32(data);

   // pictureBox1.Location = new Point(769, Y);
    }

  }

  private void SetText(string text)

 {

  // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the

  // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.

  // If these threads are different, it returns true.

 if (this.pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)

  {

    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);

    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });


  }

  else

    {

    this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(769, Convert.ToInt32( text));

  }

 }

 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

}



}
```

im receiving the Y location of client players picture box and it receives it but somehow it doesnt move correctly it just vanishes when it gets Y location the size of server n client program is same and the locations are same too so it should move like mirror

This is the game I'm trying to make left is player1 and right is player2

I also need help as to how can I update the ball position to both players and how can I properly implement multiplayer, right now I'm trying to slowly change the simple chat client code and get the data I need. but how can I get a constant player update every 20 or 50ms I'm very confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone????????????????

Comment: And where does it exactly "vanish" to? Set a breakpoint and use a debugger to check the elements position and size after they were set. Also, using pure tcp is definitely not the best idea. I'd rather use some kind of framework like WCF and execute stuff as remote functions. Also, make sure you don't send/receive data in GUI thread, as it would make your app freeze.

Comment: It moves now but just once and no update after that. I was just making this for my Network Programming exercise ...